# Web Api Routing conflict for two different controllers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, url-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

Well, I am using ASP.NET Web API 2 with attribute routing. I have two controllers with minor difference in their routes:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/menus")]
public class MenusController : ApiController {
}

[RoutePrefix("api/menus/items")]
public class MenuItemsController : ApiController {
}
```

I have all the CURD methods in both controllers. Now all the methods are working working fine except for the `POST`. Whenever I try to call `POST` method of `MenuItemsController`, I get the following error:

`Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.`

Interestingly, `POST` method of `MenusController` works perfectly OK. It's only `MenuItemsController`'s `POST` method that's causing problem.
I tried using `Order` property of `Route` as well, but in vain.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
My `POST` methods' routes are below:

- `POST api/menus/`
- `POST api/menus/items`

Comment: I think I have the same problem. I have a `GET v1/Jobs/` in one controller and e.g. `GET v1/Jobs/Materials` and `PUT v1/Jobs/{jobID}/Materials/{matID}` in a `MaterialsController`, which works fine. But when I add a PUT or POST to the `JobsController`, all controllers that use the `Jobs`-prefix in their routing break.

Answer (score 1):

**Aneeq** try to join both controllers:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/menus")]
public class MenusController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "menus";
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("api/menus")]
public class MenuItemsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("items")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "menus items";
    }
}
```

I have tested and works fine. Is it cool?

PS: I used "Get" just to simplify the solution.

Comment: Yeah it works. But the thing is my controllers are already too length. Is there no other way to make this work while keeping it organized as well?

Comment: I mean any other solution except combining the controllers?

Comment: I edited my answer i did not combine my controllers. The are two controllers check it out

Comment: Thank you for your time. 
My `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` methods are working perfectly fine. It's `POST` that's causing problem.

Comment: Aneeq, i changed my code above to "Post" and worked fine. Share your code declaration. Are you passing all the parameters? Because if you miss some parameters won't work.