# Web API Routing conflict when adding PUT method to subroute, with multiple controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm not sure how to name this problem. I also had difficulty searching for this particular issue for this reason. The closest matching question I found was [Web Api Routing conflict for two different controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40319440/1380710).

Like the asker in that question, I also have two different controllers that partially match:

```
public class JobsController : ApiController
{
    [ResponseType(typeof(DTJob[]))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {
        //...
    }

    [Route("v1/Jobs/Group"), ResponseType(typeof(DTJob[]))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFromGroup()
    {
        //...
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("v1/Jobs/{jobId}/Status"), ResponseType(typeof(string))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetStatus(long jobId)
    {
        //...
    }

    [HttpPut, Route("v1/Jobs/{jobId}/Status"), ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateStatus(long jobId, string status)
    {
        //...
    }

    //This method messes up all other controllers
    [HttpPut, Route("v1/Jobs/{jobId}"), ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(long jobId, DTJob job)
    {
        //...
    }

    //But it works if I replace the above method with the default routing pattern:
    //[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    //public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(long id, DTJob job)
    //{
    //    //...
    //}
}
```

And another controller that has a similar prefix:

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/Jobs/Materials")]
public class MaterialsController : ApiController
{
    [Route, ResponseType(typeof(DTMaterial[]))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

And my routing configs:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //...
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        //...
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Newest",
            routeTemplate: "v1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue again. Since the `{jobId}` is not specified in type, it could potentially be a string that says "Materials", creating the conflict. To resolve this, I could just specify the type in the parameter (`{jobId:long}`):

```
    [HttpPut, Route("v1/Jobs/{jobId:long}"), ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(long jobId, DTJob job)
    {
        //...
    }
```